# Can we send a message from iwatch to Iphone when iphone in sleep mode?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch

I am new to Apple Watch i am tried to Communicate From Apple watch to Iphone when Iphone is in sleep mode because i have to get some information from my Iphone application when i click on the notification on my apple watch.

we tried this links but these links are not working for me.

[Can I keep my WatchKit App running in the background on the Apple Watch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792260/can-i-keep-my-watchkit-app-running-in-the-background-on-the-apple-watch)

http://techotopia.com/index.php/A_watchOS_2_WatchConnectivity_Messaging_Tutorial

[How can I awake my iPhone app in the background to run a function and return the results to Apple Watch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911706/how-can-i-awake-my-iphone-app-in-the-background-to-run-a-function-and-return-the)

Please help me.

Comment: Just Check about

- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveUserInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)userInfo

Called on the delegate of the receiver. Will be called on startup if the user info finished transferring when the receiver was not running.